# Why can't I store data on the stack properly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler, intel-syntax

I'm writing a compiler, and it emitted the following (Intel-syntax) assembly code for Linux (x86-64):

```
lea r13, _s1
mov qword ptr [rbp + -2*8], r13
mov r10, qword ptr [rbp + -2*8]
lea r13, qword ptr [r10 + 8]
```

If I'm reading this correctly, this code is supposed to load the address of label `_s1` into `r13`, store it on the stack, read it from the stack into `r10`, add 8, and store the reuslt in `r13`. That matches the expected behaviour of my program, and it seems to work as expected (program doesn't crash here) when I am not debugging the program.

However, when I try to debug the program using VSCode with CodeLLDB, as I step through the program, I see behaviour that I can't understand. This is what seems to happen according to CodeLLDB:

- `lea    r13, [0x425290]`: `0x425290` is loaded into `r13`
- `mov    qword ptr [rbp - 0x10], r13`: `0x425290` is written to address `0x7fffffffe1f0`; I confirmed this by running `memory read -s1 $rbp-0x10` in LLDB
- `mov    r10, qword ptr [rbp - 0x10]`: `0xffffe6f400000000` is read into `r10`. **Why?**
- `lea    r13, [r10 + 0x8]`: `0xffffe6f400000008` is loaded into `r13`

Why is the value that I read back from the stack different from the value that I wrote into it?

**Edit:** It seems like this weird behaviour doesn't happen when I use VSCode's built-in GDB debugger. Am I misusing LLDB?

Comment: Did you remember to adjust the stack pointer to the bottom of your stack frame?  Some debugger features need scratch memory in the program's address space, and will often use the stack below the stack pointer.  What's the value in `rsp` while this is going on?

Comment: Did you even set up `rbp` to point to your stack frame?

Comment: @NateEldredge @Jester I used `enter 0x140, 0` to set up the stack frame. `rbp = 0x00007fffffffe200`, `rsp = 0x00007fffffffe0c0`

Comment: That certainly looks correct.

Comment: @Jester it's a total head-scratcher, because it works fine when I use a different debugger (such as command-line GDB, or CLion GDB) or no debugger

Comment: Could you show the complete transcript of your debugger session?

Comment: `lea r13, _s1` is odd, using a `[disp32]` absolute addressing mode.  In GAS Intel syntax, you want `lea r13, [rip + _s1]` for a normal RIP-relative addressing mode that will work when loaded at any address.  Probably not your problem, though, since you do show the address being in the low 31 bits of virtual address space, where you could have used `mov r13d, OFFSET _s1` if you wanted to take advantage of it fitting in 32-bit absolute. ([How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012))

Comment: This isn't a [mcve], at least without the info from comments about RSP and RBP values.  You're sure that there's no signal handler that might have a pointer to that stack space?  Or that you didn't execute a `leave` or something before these instructions, or especially *between* them so RBP points somewhere else?   (BTW, `enter` is pretty inefficient; use `push rbp` / `mov rbp, rsp` / `sub rsp, ...` like GCC/clang do. `leave` is not bad, GCC uses it when a single `pop rbp` won't do.)